# Do I have to set up 2 EC2 instances in order to use AWS ACM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I have one EC2 instance and I would like to set up HTTPS based on ACM.

So it seems I must place an ELB between my EC2 instance and the DNS records if I wish to use ACM's certificate.

ELB writes I must specify subnets from at least two Availability Zones.

The EC2 instance is located in one particular Availability Zone.

So do I have any other choice other than duplicating this EC2 ? Is there any way to use ACM + ELB with only one EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more options to place the ACM other than on the ELB:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html

But if you are still wanting to use the ELB, you can just pick one subnet, or pick n subnets and leave n-1 unatended, there is no problem the requests are going to be routed to the one with an instance.

Answer (score 0):

An ELB can point to a single EC2 instance. You don't have to have an active EC2 instance in each availability zone the ELB is configured for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a certificate with one EC2 instance you should consider whether or not using ACM makes sense versus configuring a certificate yourself. If you don't need load balancing it probably doesn't make sense to pay for the ELB. You could consider using a Cloudfront distribution and installing the certificate there. More info: [How to add SSL certificate to AWS EC2 with the help of new AWS Certificate Manager service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945299/how-to-add-ssl-certificate-to-aws-ec2-with-the-help-of-new-aws-certificate-manag)