# Apache VirtualHost http and https

Tags: apache

I have a site example.com and setup a VirtualHost to redirect to https://www.example.com

When I go to http://example.com it works great, however https does not

How can I update my VirtualHost configuration to also direct https traffic?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect permanent "/" "https://www.example.com"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect permanent "/" "https://www.example.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

The top one works great and redirects as expected, but https://example.com does not

Confirmed in AWS that the instance allows all traffic on both ports 80 and 443

--update

This is hosted on an AWS EC2 instance, and the HTTPS certificate in question was issued via the AWS Certificate Manager. Per Shim's suggestion I looked at https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts but it requires me to export a certificate which AWS does not permit? Is there another way around this?

Comment: Try to read the documentation here : https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts . You have to enable mod_ssl and create certificates for your domains.

Comment: Thanks Shim, I have an SSL and wildcard certificate already. Will try to follow this guide.

Comment: @Shim-Sao Please see my update if you have a moment. The server is hosted on AWS EC2 and its sole purpose is a direct. With the certificate in AWS, how can I perform this https redirect?

Comment: @Prix The official guide suggests using a self-signed (which gives the user an error) or one from a CA. Unfortunately, we're using an AWS ACM certificate which you cannot export the public one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184572/discussion-between-joshua-ohana-and-prix).

Comment: Unfortunately that's only for private certificates not public

Comment: Maybe this discussion can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945299/how-to-add-ssl-certificate-to-aws-ec2-with-the-help-of-new-aws-certificate-manag . It seems that what you are doing is not allowed.

Comment: I also found this : https://aws.amazon.com/fr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/

Comment: Here is a tutorial to install free ssl on AWS EC2 : https://hackernoon.com/getting-a-free-ssl-certificate-on-aws-a-how-to-guide-6ef29e576d22

Comment: Thanks those were all workarounds to avoid using the way I had it existing setup. I ended up resolving the need for this workaround in the first place so no longer need this.